# WCF server logging with client operation (Devexpress,XPO,serilog)

Tags: winforms, wcf, service, devexpress, serilog

I have WCF service with XPO and i want to make uniform log system where i logging all event. We are using Session instanced of unit of work and we are using .NET and Winform. log data Example: service method call name,duration, Database operations.
I can't find a solution that, i can log the client site operation (devexpress) to server site (WCF).
Example the session.save method is not contract methods therefore, i can't to catch with IOperationInvoker.
What is the solution?

Comment: Is it OK to consolidate the client logs and send them to the server?

Comment: No, i want to log everything on the server site